# Chronosys box outline shows unwanted line

Tags: line, options, chronosys

I'm making a timeline using [`chronosys`](http://ctan.mirror.rafal.ca/macros/latex/contrib/chronosys/docchronosys_en.pdf) package.

It worked well but when I choose the `box=true` option in the \startchronology, a line popped just before the arrow and I can't make it disappear.

Here is the picture I get and the code:

[image]

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{chronosys} 

\begin{document}
\begin{figure} \centering

    %Definition of accidents that are going to be inside the time line
    \definechronoevent{Acc}[icon=X, iconheight=2.2cm, textwidth=2cm,
    barre=false, mark=false, markdepth=-0.8cm, colorbox=black!20,
    ]
        
    \begin{chronology}[startyear=1975,stopyear=2015,
        color=black!20, box=true, %% Here the option that makes the outline
        height=3cm, width=15cm,
        ]
        
        %European Laws          
        \chronoevent[markdepth=2cm]{2012}{SEVESO~III} 

        %% Here the depth of the mark affect the depth of the unwanted outline 
        
        %Accidents
        \chronoAcc {1976}{Seveso (Italie)}      %10/07/1976
    \end{chronology}
    
    \caption{Caption}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

the documentation says:

> box :
> boolean which indicates if the timeline should be passed back with a black line.
> It must be either true or false and it is false by default

I can't find any exemple on the internet where this option is used so I don't know if it's a known issue.
I could obviously use this grey color and remove the outline but I would prefer having a white background.

Side question: the arrow is not completely aligned it's a little upward I don't know if there is a easy way to fix this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem can be traced back to a single (incorrect) line in the `chronosyschr.tex` file included with the distribution. (From [CTAN in here](https://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/chronosys.zip))

The original line #196

`\kern\!chr!realwidth \vrule height\!chrheight\relax\kern-0.4pt\relax`

must be changed by

`\kern\!chr!realwidth  \vrule height\!chrheight depth\z@\relax\kern-0.4pt\relax`

Download the file for the link and edit it.
This can be done with a text editor or with your LaTeX editor. You can save the modified file to your working directory to keep the original intact.

You might also contact the maintainer of the package.

[image: a]

[image: b]

**UPDATE** after follow-up question

To delete the vertical line between the rectangle and the triangle, you must delete two lines: the one coming from the right side of the rectangle and the other from the vertical side of the triangle.

To remove the first one, edit the `chronosyschr.tex`  file and change line 196 from

`\kern\!chr!realwidth \vrule height\!chrheight\relax\kern-0.4pt\relax`

to

`\kern\!chr!realwidth\vrule height\z@ depth\z@\relax \kern-0.4pt\relax%`

To remove the second: **(a)** change the line 213 from

`\!chrfilldraw[color=\!chr@arrowcolor](0,0.5*\the\!chrarrowheight-0.4pt)--(\the\!chrarrowwidth,0)--(0,-0.5*\the\!chrarrowheight)--cycle;`

to

`\!chrfilldraw[color=\!chr@arrowcolor](-0.6pt,0.5*\the\!chrarrowheight-0.6pt)--(\the\!chrarrowwidth,0)--(-0.6pt,-0.5*\the\!chrarrowheight-0.2pt)--cycle;`

and **(b)** change the line 215 from

`\!chrdraw[color=black](-0.4pt,0.5*\the\!chrarrowheight+0.4pt)--(\the\!chrarrowwidth+0.4pt,0)--(-0.4pt,-0.5*\the\!chrarrowheight-0.4pt)--cycle;`

to

`\!chrdraw[color=black](-0.5pt,0.5*\the\!chrarrowheight-0.4pt)--(\the\!chrarrowwidth+0.4pt,0)--(-0.5pt,-0.5*\the\!chrarrowheight-0.4pt);`

Save the edited file in your working directory.

If you see a faint white line between the rectangle and the triangle, it is an artifact of the PDF viewer

[image: x]

[image: y]

[image: z]

Comment: Do you know if there is also a way to remove the vertical line that joins the rectangle and the triangle?

Comment: @BlueMarker Please see the updated answer.

Comment: Thank you for your prompt answer that's exactly what was needed.