# Chronosys arrow is not aligned and the color filling is messy

Tags: arrows, alignment, fill, chronosys

I'm making a timeline using [`chronosys`](http://ctan.mirror.rafal.ca/macros/latex/contrib/chronosys/docchronosys_en.pdf) package.

I noticed that the arrow head is not perfectly aligned with the rectangle of the timeline, even in the documentation...
It's not that noticeable using the color option but when the box option is used (which outlines the timeline) the shift is visible.
[image: Misalignement of the arrow head in the documentation p.20]

Above picture shows the misalignement of the arrow head in the documentation p.20.

Here is a what I get with the following code:

[image: Whole timeline produced by the code][image: Zoom at the bottom of the arrow head]

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{chronosys} 

\begin{document}
\begin{figure} \centering       
    \begin{chronology}
        [startyear=2005,stopyear=2015, dates=false,
        color=black!20, box=true,
        height=1cm, width=2cm,
        ]
                
    \end{chronology}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

We can see that on top of not being perfectly aligned, there is also a problem with the coloring of the head (which is not important for me as I want the color to be white but might be of use for others)

Comment: This seems to be a pretty old package. Ti*k*Z has had many updates since 2012 and I think `chronosys` may not have kept up. You might have better success using Ti*k*Z directly. There is also a `timeline` library (though I haven't used it).

Comment: I corrected some of this anomalies in my updated answer https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/676396/161015

Answer (score 1):

[`chronos`](https://codeberg.org/cfr/chronos/) allows you to specify the arrow using the usual Ti*k*Z syntax and draws it using the standard Ti*k*Z methods.

[image: chronos arrow]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{chronos}% https://codeberg.org/cfr/chronos/
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\begin{document}
\begin{chronos}
  [
    timeline={
      dates=2005:2015,
      width'=20mm,
      height'=10mm,
      timeline years=none,
      timeline line={
        -{Triangle[open,black,fill=gray,line width=.4pt,length=5mm,width=12mm]},
      },
      timeline foreground=gray,
    },
  ]
\end{chronos}
\end{document}
```